# Hough Transform Algorithm for Text Detection in Images

Tags: java, algorithm, text, pattern-recognition, hough-transform

Hough Transform Algorithm is one of the algorithm use for text line detection and edge detection.

Does Hough Transform Algorithm can be use for Detecting text in Images?

What must be the process or implementation in java for this question? or It must be have another algorithm to make it possilble?

Hoping for positive response.

Comment: If you want to test algorithms matlab is your friend. Implementing hough transform on your own is not the way to go.  You can search for a code in matlab.  Or use open cv.

Answer (score 2):

Hough transform was initially designed to detect straight lines in an image, but later modifications have been proposed to use similar logic to detect circles or other shapes. However letters and text is a bit more complex and can(most of the time) be described with a simple shape. Thus applying Hough transform directly is not possible.

However Hough transform can be used as part of the solution. For instance you can detect straight lines and this can help you detect separate letters or to recognize some special letters. Also sometimes Hough can be used to detect text direction which is a challenging problem on its own.

Text recognition is a very interesting problem and many different solutions have been proposed. In fact there are whole courses dedicated to that and new approaches appear often. I personally like approaches that use neural networks the most. Have a look [here](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/feneric/charrecnn.html) for instance.

Comment: So what could be te best algorithm tht can suite the Hough Transform for dtecting text in images?
Thanks