# Algorithm that suits for pattern recognition

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, hough-transform

Computer Vision and Artificial  Intelligence. Well pattern recognition nowadays are particularly known to people. I'm a student and I'm doing a study about pattern recognition which I have to match a pattern  to check if the pattern is match. And I'm using the Hough Algorithm for the detection of ellipses. The question is what would suit Hough Algorithm for pattern matching? and what is process of it. I am hoping  for everyone's positive response. Thanks

Comment: Why do you tag this as regex?

Comment: The site suggested me to tag it. Do I have to remove it?

Comment: The site uses some kind of *machine learning* to guess the tags you should use. If your question however, asks for something differently you should rewrite the tags. This is done now.

Comment: do you mean a circle, or an ellipse. And in the case of an ellipse, is the *width/height* ratio known a priori?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25894050/50447

Answer (score 0):

The *Hough* transformation is some kind of *inverse* image transformation that uses voting.

In other words, if your pattern is a circle, you look for the centers of images. This is done using voting and inversing the image.

The inverse of a circle is, *ironically enough* another circle. If a pixel has a high intensity, it is likely it is part of some circle (or at least, that's the hypothesis). Now that means we will *vote* on all pixels with a radius *R* from that circle, because all these pixels are potential candidates for being the midpoint of a circle.

Because we expect that *all* the pixels of the circle(s) we are looking for are part of the image, the real midpoint will receive way more votes than some pixels that happen to be potential midpoints of two or three pixels. Pixels with enough votes are considered to be "real" circle midpoints.

As a preprocessing step, the image should be manipulated, for instance using (Canny) edge detection so that only the surface of the circle is highlighted. Such transformations are in many cases somehow application specific.

You can perform the same transformation on all kinds of images, but for some images, they can be optimized (since the image is symmetrical, etc.)

Comment: after the transformation of image how would i determine if that image has the same pattern as the other image?

Comment: If the image after the Hough transformation contains one or more pixels with a huge intensity level...

Comment: can i also ask about thresholding? if its ok? or should i create another forum?

Comment: how does the thresholding works on images? what does it done to the  image? and what property of the image does thresholding do?

Comment: The intensity: you define a value and when the intensity level is higher than that value, you assume that the (center of) the pattern is located there...

Answer (score 0):

In the Hough transform, a main idea is to consider the characteristics of the shape not as discrete image points (x1, y1), (x2, y2), etc., but instead, in terms of its parameters For, e.g., the slope parameter m and the intercept parameter b can be used to represent line in parametric space.(However due to vertical line we don't use this form intstead prefer the equation of line written using parameters, b and angle-> see for detail(http://www.tpub.com/math2/6.htm)). Now we can have each line in image with unique parameters. (see for details: http://www.ai.sri.com/pubs/files/tn036-duda71.pdf ).

However with some  modification, the Hough Transform can be used for not only the detection of an object described with an analytic equation (e.g. line, circle, etc.). Instead, it can also be used to detect an arbitrary object described with its model. This is called Generalised Hough Transform or GHT. (see for details: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~dana/HoughT.pdf)